# How to overlay a simple div directly on top of a simple html table td?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple html table where each tr has a td for a label and a td for content. I'm looking for the most correct / efficient way to draw a div over the top of the "content td" leaving the label visible. The plan is to make the second td "hidden" by the overlay if possible. (I've got bootstrap 3 included on the page if that helps in any way)

Thank you in advance

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>My Label</td>
    <td>Overlay some div on top of this element</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I don't yet have it in the DOM (although it could be present and just hidden if that make this process quicker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you insert a div into the content td and use position absolute. Like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/8RuZe/](http://jsfiddle.net/8RuZe/1/)

```
td.content {
    position: relative;
}
div.over {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

I've tested this method on all major browsers from IE8 to IE11.

Good luck.